# Can't boot VirtualBox vdi virtual machine image converted to raw image in QEMU/KVM: not a bootable disk

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, qemu, linux-kvm

I have a .vdi VM image created with VirtualBox and converted it to raw and qcow2 images like this:

```
VBoxManage clonehd --format RAW ./vm.vdi ./vm.img

qemu-img convert -f raw ./vm.img -O qcow2 ./vm.qcow2

qemu-img convert -f vdi -O qcow2 ./vm.vdi ./vm2.qcow2
```

But when I try to run either of these with aQEMU I get:

```
Booting from Hard Disk...
Boot failed: not a bootable disk
No bootable device
```

I also get this when running it via command-line (without aqemu) with `-drive file="./vm.img",format=raw`

I encrypted the VM in VirtualBox - maybe that's the problem? Is it possible to decrypt it without VirtualBox if it is? How to get the vm working with QEMU on GNU/Linux?

Comment: I would suspect that the encryption is the problem. I've converted (5) different VB images the exact same way and none of them failed to boot with QEMU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to decrypt the vm (from another machine in my case) before converting it:

1. Remove the encryption by unchecking the encryption setting under General -> Disk encryption
2. To restore (migrate) the current state of the VM (the latest snapshot) right click the VM -> Clone -> Full clone -> Current machine state
3. Convert the resulting .vdi file to a .qcow2 file by running 
   `qemu-img convert -f vdi -O qcow2 ./vm.vdi ./vm2.qcow2`
4. Create a new vm with aqemu (couldn't find a way to import the vm configuration) and add the .qcow2 file under Media -> Add devices